# WiFi.scanNetworks() sometimes triggers wdt reset

Tags: esp32, wifi, watchdog

In my sketch for ESP32, I call the network scanning function:

```
WiFi.scanNetworks(true);
```

but sometimes it trigger a wdt reset:

```
E (372741) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (372741) task_wdt:  - async_tcp (CPU 0/1)
E (372741) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (372741) task_wdt: CPU 0: IDLE
E (372741) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE
E (372741) task_wdt: Aborting.

abort() was called at PC 0x40113f64 on core 0

Backtrace: 0x40083db5:0x3ffbf1ac |<-CORRUPTED
```

I added these lines in the `setup()` with no changes in the behavior:

```
disableCore0WDT();
disableCore1WDT();
disableLoopWDT();
```

EDIT:

My questions are:

1. "Why it triggers a WDT reset even if I disabled the WDT?"
2. "Why a scan network triggers a WDT reset? It should be a stock function"

Comment: what is your question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: @jsotola done. Please tell me if now the questions are clear and answerable, or how to improve them further

Comment: `WiFi.scanNetworks(true);` means async WiFi scan, it is non-blocking, so anything that causing the WDT trigger is in your code and we don't know how you setup the task and handing the state transitions. Do you have any problem running WiFi scan with sync mode `WiFi.scanNetworks();`?

Comment: @hcheung I'm fairly certain that it might be something inside Espressif's proprietary RF driver code. All of the task's setup and everything is hidden away as well from most Arduino users, so I don't think we'll be able to answer #2. For #1, it's because there is also a WDT for tasks, while the disabled WDTs are the "loop WDTs".